# Checking for more than 2 things in an array with array.includes()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am making a tic tac toe based in pure JS however while defining the win conditions for the players i want it to alert the user when the conditions are matched..

When a box is checked if . it is X  who plays it turns red and if it is O's turn then blue and it also registers the id of the box element into an array containing all the boxes that are occupied also depending if the box is red or blue it also tags the id along with a 0 , 1 (0 is red 1 is blue)

so the array looks like this (11,0 22,1 33,0) 11 is first row 1st column 0 means red has occupied that spot (red = X)

In the past i have tried array.includes to check if the boxes that are already clicked are in a row or a diagonal and if they are also checked by the same player.. 
i used an and operator so it checks if 3 in a row are checked by the same player.. so that only if all three in a row are checked it alerts the win. I have stored the boolean value in redwincond bluewincond

```
function logic(clickedArr) {
    redwinCond = clickedArr.contains(("11,0") && ("22,0") && ("33,0"));

    bluewinCond = clickedArr.contains(("11,1") && ("22,1") && ("33,1"));

    console.log(bluewinCond, redwinCond)

    if (redwinCond === true) {
        alert("Red wins !")
    } else if (bluewinCond === true) {
        alert("Blue wins !")
    } else {

    }    
}
```

*example* `redwinCond = clickedArr.contains(("11,0") && ("22,0") && ("33,0"));`
Expected result:  after all 3 are checked by the same color alerts user

Result: only when the third box specified (33,0) is clicked it alerts. doesnt check if other 2 are checked also CHECKED

Comment: Good suggestions below to use `every`-- here is a link to more detail on what it does and how it works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every You'll also note it enjoys good browser support.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any method named `contains` for Array instead of that you can use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method along with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) methods.

```
 ["11,0", "22,0", "33,0"].every(v => clickedArr.includes(v))
```

**FYI :** In your code `("11,0") && ("22,0") && ("33,0")` will reults `"33,0"` since all the other values are truthy.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks to that library that cocked it up for the entire internet, we are stuck with this mistake.

Comment: But even if I start the game with the (33,0) it will consider it as a win .. even though it is the first turn in the game

Comment: @Kingzel : you have to manage that ... check array size or something else

Comment: @PranavCBalan what array only has 3 values so far it shouldnt be a prolem

Comment: @Kingzel :  you need to call it only at the end of the game or you have to check win case for blue as well

Comment: @PranavCBalan i am already checking the case for blue too i just didnt show it in the code because the problem is with the array.includes()

Comment: @Kingzel the same way you have to check for blue.... using every and includes....

Comment: @Kingzel :  check the value of `clickedArr` as well... it will only true if all those values are present in the array

Comment: any other way other than .every method also where am i going wrong

Comment: @Kingzel : can you share the value of array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192018/discussion-between-kingzel-and-pranav-c-balan).

Answer (score 1):

Use `every`:

```
["11,0", "22,0", "33,0"].every(s => clickedArr.includes(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way would be to store your board state, instead of every storing every click. It'll make your life a lot simpler. For example, one way to do it would be to store it in nested arrays like this:

```
var board = [
    ['x', '', 'o'],
    ['x', '', ''],
    ['',  '', '']
];
```

The top-right square would be accessed like: `board[0][2]`.
You also can iterate the rows and columns in your win checking function instead of having to hardcode every row and column manually.